# HVAC board is reading 32v, is this OK?

Tags: electrical, hvac

The voltage reading on my HVAC board where the thermostat cable is connected to is as follow:

- R-W:26V
- R-Y:32V
- R-G:32v
- R-B:32v

Is that reading normal? What should I check for?

I'm starting to think this might be why I'm having problem with my Nest thermostat (24 volt max) which will keep turning on and off my HVAC every 30 seconds. It runs fine on my old thermostat.

Comment: Was your Nest thermostat connected by a functioning C-wire? (it doesn't *need* to be, but if it's not certain tricks may be necessary to keep ^^ from happening).  Are you *sure* the wire you think is C is actually C, and not some other function?   If you disconnect all wires but R and C, does the Nest power up, backlight and interact normally? (count complaints of missing wires in the "normal" category lol).

Comment: The blue wire is connected to the c symbol on board where the thermostat cables are connected to and it gave out 32 volt reading. I'll try your way. But does that reading look normal or should I check the transformer?

Comment: It's a little high but I am not too worried about. What I proposed is not "a better way to wire it", but rather a diagnostic to see if the C wire is working.

Comment: yeah, that's how I took it, as a troubleshooting step to see whether the C is actually working. Thank you!! I'll give it a shot when I get home this weekend.

Comment: If nest was really 24V max many installs would not work, it's obviously more than 24V,  but I can't say if 32V is acceptable, and the people who can say seem to be lying.